# Is there a way to spoof the return address on a message using NServiceBus?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I'm building a web site that sends commands to other endpoints in order to
effect changes in the domain. In the event that a command fails for a business
reason, I'd like to be able to use `Bus.Reply()` and send a command failure message
to an endpoint at the `ReturnAddress` specified in the `TransportMessage`.

In attempting to accomplish this, I've set up the `MsmqTransportConfig` in my
web.config to have the appropriate `InputQueue` value; the `Bus.Reply()` call then works
correctly. However, when the reply is received in the specified queue, the web
site proceeds to consume it, which is not what I want to happen; I have another endpoint listening to the same queue to consume these events.

Is there a way to have NServiceBus use the `ReturnAddress` header on the sent
message, or a way to instruct a process not to pay attention to the
iput queue specified in `MsmqTransportConfig`, or a way to set the `ReturnAddress` value programatically on the `TransportMessage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it is possible to do this.  Here is the configuration block I ended up using:

```
var config = Configure.WithWeb().StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IContainer>()).XmlSerializer();
config.UnicastBus().MsmqTransport();
config.Configurer
    .ConfigureComponent<MsmqTransport>(ComponentCallModelEnum.Singleton)
    .ConfigureProperty(t => t.InputQueue, "MyReturnQueue");
config.CreateBus().Start();
```

I haven't looked through the code yet to figure out exactly what is happening, but it appears that if there is not an `MsmqTransportConfig` entry in the web.config file, the transport will not listen on its input queue. So by setting the `InputQueue` property programatically before the bus is created, the `ReturnAddress` of the `TransportMessage` gets populated, but the bus does not consume messages at that address.